# How to use hibernate search criteria on parameter with set

Tags: java, hibernate

I have several entities where one of them has a parameter with Set containing other entities from many-to-many join like this (I am using only two of them for simplicity).
How can I use search criteria to filter out Users who have Avatar with id==1?

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private String loginId;
    private String screenName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Avatar> avatars;
}

@Entity
public class Avatar
{
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "loginId"))
    private User user;
    private String url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native query in order to obtain what you want. 
The syntax will look like this:

```
 @Query(
    value = "select * from ...",
    nativeQuery = true
)
```

Maybe you can refactor the tables from database without affecting the business logic. I don't know what requirements do you have but I think you can use @ManyToOne.

Answer (score 0):

You can use root.join to achieve this.

```
int avatarId = 1;
CriteriaQuery<User> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> user = query.from(User.class); 
criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal (
    user.join("avatars").get("id"), avatarId));
```